# Discordpy store role mentions as strings

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have this command for making the bot write in any channel I want, the thing is that I also want to be able to mention with it, so I tried to change the args that start with @ and convert it into a role mention, but it seems that I can't just store a role mention in the args. Any sugestions to change certain args with mentions?

```
async def echo(ctx, id, *echowords: str):
if ctx.message.author.id in [212620735754010624]:
    sendchannel = client.get_channel(int(id))
    for i in range(len(echowords)):
        if echowords[i].startswith("@ "):
            echowords[i] = get(
                sendchannel.guild.roles, name=echowords[i].replace("@ ", "")
            ).mention

    await sendchannel.send(" ".join(echowords[:]))
else:
    await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it all solved using a list instead of a tuple.

```
async def echo(ctx, id, *echowords: str):
if ctx.message.author.id in [212620735754010624]:
    msg = list()
    sendchannel = client.get_channel(int(id))
    for i in range(len(echowords)):
        if echowords[i].startswith("@ "):
            msg.append(
                get(
                    sendchannel.guild.roles, name=echowords[i].replace("@ ", "")
                ).mention
            )
        else:
            print(str(i))
            msg.append(echowords[i])
    await sendchannel.send(" ".join(msg[:]))
else:
    await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")
```

Answer (score 0):

`discord.Role` has the attribute `mention` which gives you the string to mention the role. If you're trying to turn a string with the name of the role into the `Role`, you can loop through `Guild.roles` and find the role that matches the name. A better solution would likely be to store the mention string of the role, the ID of the role, or the `Role` itself to avoid checking the whole list of roles each time.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.mention

Comment: While in the documentation says that it gives you a string, it seems it actually gives me an object. So I can't put it in the echowords tuple.